# How to replace [at] to @?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm wondering how to replace [at] to @ when jQuery loads...

This code

```
<p id="nospam">myself[at]myemail.com</p>
```

If you think is not useful against spambots... your suggestions are always welcome!

Comment: Why do you use this [at] anyway? Most spam bots are probably taught to recognize it.

Comment: Then maybe i should to use [hiwhatsupspambotyoucantseethis]... what about it?

Comment: I think the best method against spambot is to have a good spam filter on your inbox. Showing email addresses as images might stop most spambots but is an inconvenience to your users that won't be able to copy it.

Comment: This idea to change e-mails dynamically is actually very good. Just hide them better in the static part.

Comment: Images? well it was old news and it's impossible to copy this e-mail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#nospam").text(function(i,t){
  return t.replace("[at]","@");
});
```

Using the function form of [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a simple way to not have to repeat your selector code or waste time re-selecting the element or its value.

Comment: It worked, but i have a little problem, it only replaces one <p id="nospam"></p> tag, not another next two tags

Comment: @Ivan: The `id` is unique, you can't have two elements with the same ID. Just use `class`es: `<p class="nospam">...` and `$('.nospam')`

Answer (score 3):

I see that you want to change multiple e-mails like this. The problem is that 2 or more elements cannot have the same `id`. But `class`es are made just for this.

```
<p class="nospam">myself[at]myemail.com</p>
```

You can select all the items with `nospam` class like this: `$('.nospam')`

Then you can use [*Phrogz*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840597/how-to-replace-at-to/7840638#7840638) as in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W9uGr/)

Comment: Yes, this is my mistake to create "id". Then i replaced them "id" to "class" Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#nospam").text($("#nospam").text().replace("[at]", "@"));
```

Comment: It works, but only it replaces to unique tag, not three tags with [at]

Comment: @Ivan that's because it's not valid to have more than one element with the same id. Uses classes instead.

Comment: Yes, i already got comments from another guys told "id" should to replace with "class" thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var anchor = $('#nospam');
  var text = anchor.text();
  anchor.text(text.replace('[at]', '@'));
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vN8NY/